# package does not exist error when I run java program in a bat file from Task Scheduler... But It will run when a bat file double clicked

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

Shows an error running from task schedular

[image: Shows an error running from task schedular]

Runs perfectly by double clicking the bat file

[image: Runs perfectly by double clicking the bat file]

Please give me suggestions to run the bat file from task scheduler....
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you mention the classpath libraries while running the TaskScheduler. Seems like the libraries are missing and not on the classpath

Comment: Please set the path in SystemEnvironment Varibale.

Comment: I remember it is using a different user (by default) when executing in task scheduler.  That user's path, classpath etc setting can be totally different from your own user (which is used to execute the batch directly).

Answer (score 0):

When you double-click, the process executes in the same directory as the file you clicked. You need to tell the Task Scheduler what working directory you want. Set it to the same as the batch file.

It's very curious to both compile and execute the code via the scheduler. Surely you're going to deploy a JAR file, not source code?